# Fetching id of parent node from child node in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

1000
    
          
                 ...some data

```
      <component id="2">
               ...some data
      </component>
               ....
               ....
      <component id="10">
                ...some data
      </component>
 </components>
```

```
I have the above XMl and I want to fetch data from all the components for a particular idea. (For eg. 1000). Currently I'm using record as component.
```

new Ext.data.Store({
          reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
              record:'component',
              id:'id'
          }, [
           ...Data to fetched
     ]
 })

I'm not able to fetch idea id. I tried using the parentNode.getAttribute() function but due to some reasons it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a store for this application.

If you're only interested in pulling the "...some data" out of a component, it's much easier to use a DomQuery.

For example:

```
var component = Ext.DomQuery('component[id=1000]', xmlParentNode);
```

This would return an XML node named "component" with a property of id that equals 1000.

See http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.DomQuery for more details.

Hope this helps